# FileNotFoundException for the jar name

Tags: java, jar, filenotfoundexception

I tried to generate a jar, but got the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Ass6Game.jar (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:131)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1022)
```

This is the command I used: `jar -cmf Ass6Game.jar Manifest.txt -C bin . -C src resources`.

The point of origin for the classpath contains a bin and src folders, the Manifest.txt file and the makefile.

I have in the bin folder various packages and stuff and a resources folder inside the src folder that I want to be beside the packages inside the jar.

Once again, what did I do wrong?

Comment: I think it needs to be MANIFEST.MD

and it needs to contain valid stuff

Comment: I used Manifest.txt in other jars and it worked perfectly.

Comment: does your manifest have valid stuff in it, or is it empty?

Comment: Valid stuff - only specification of the main class, really.

Comment: Just make sure you have everything.

Comment: I'll wait for someone who can actually help then.